# Hide visiblity of UI router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have specified route as

```
 .state('executive.vieworder', {
                abstarct: true,
                url: '/order/:id/',
                templateUrl: './partials/order/view.html',
                controller: 'OrderViewCtrl'
            })
```

I need the url to be hidden in the browse address bar. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want your URL not to show `order/:some_id/` ?

Comment: Yes. I need to work as usual. But the address bar must not show the same

Comment: Why do you not want to change the URL - can you explain this a little?

Comment: for the working, i require the url. But for security reason I need to hide this url in the browser address bar

Comment: Apparently, it is not possible to use the way you want. However, you can always remove `url: '/order/:id/',` from your code if you are not going to use `$stateParams`. This way, the URL will not be modified.